# Where to put "useDotenv: true" in serverless.yml file?

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, serverless-architecture

I was using serverless templates and all worked fine until suddenly all my deployments started ignoring `.env` files.

I searched through the [documentation](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/environment-variables/) and it says that if I want to use the environment variables from .env files I now have to add `useDotenv: true` in my `serverless.yml` file. So I did:

```
app: xxx
org: xxx
useDotenv: true
```

There was no effect.

My `serverless.yml` file contained nothing else before but the app and org variables.

Where do I need to add the `seDotenv: true` in order to make it read my `.env` variables?

Comment: It needs to go right in the same level where your `service` definition is, e.g. `service: my-service` then next line on that level add `useDotenv: true`. Which Serverless version are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The accepted answer is the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should put it at the root of your serverless.yml file.

I have mine just after the service attribute :

```
service: lb-courses
useDotenv: true
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
...
```